# n-point Fekete set of the unit closed disc

Tags: calculus, geometry

For any a compact $E \subset \mathbb{C}$, let $\mathcal{E}_{n}=\{A \subset E:|A|=n\}$ be those subsets of $E$ with $n$ elements.
For $A=\left\{z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right\} \in \mathcal{E}_{n}$, let $\Delta_{A}$ be product of distances among its elements:
$$
\Delta_{A}=\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq n}\left|z_{i}-z_{j}\right|
$$
Among all $A \in \mathcal{E}_{n}$, those maximizes $\Delta_{A}$ is called an **$n$-point Fekete set** of $E$.

It is well known that for $E=[-1,1]$, its $n$-point Fekete set $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ is known to be unique and
$$
z \in \mathcal{F}_{n} \Longleftrightarrow\left(1-z^{2}\right) P_{\ell}^{\prime}(z)=0
$$
where $\ell=n-1$ and $P_{\ell}(z)$ is the Legendre polynomial of order $\ell$.

**My question is, if $E$ is the unit closed disc, i.e., $E = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq 1\}$, what is its $n$-point Fekete set, which may be not unique?**

I had checked some literature, but I didn’t find the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The question is solved for $n\leq 18$ in [Computing Fekete and Lebesgue points: Simplex, square, disk](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042711006133) by Briani, Sommariva, Vianello.
They numerically solved some non-linear optimisation problems in order to find their result.
As far as I am aware no general solution is known.